# Databricks - Tag in job Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-workflows

I have a doubt regarding how to tag the cluster of the job cluster in databricks via api.

I know that I can already tag a cluster and the job, but I wanted to tag the cluster of the cluster job, is this possible?

I tried to use the "jobs/update" endpoint to insert the tag in the job cluster and even inserting these fields it still gets the same error:

**Example of request:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://databricks.com/api/2.0/jobs/update' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "job_id": 123456789,
    "new_settings": {
        "job_clusters": [
            {
                "job_cluster_key": "test",
                "new_cluster": {
                    "custom_tags": {"test": "123"}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

[image]

I want to tag the resource (cluster) within the cluster job, is it possible via api? Has anyone performed this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into [Jobs API documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsUpdate), you may see that you need to provide all configuration parameters for block that you're updating, not only changed nested fields.  Basically, this API allows you to change only top-level fields of the job, and do it completely, not nested fields.

P.S. I'll ask docs team to provide clarification there.

Comment: Thank you @Alex, with that I was able to understand how it works and it worked here, thank you very much